# Is it possible to update a variable in python from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I have a bokeh server application that displays data in a graph.

I want to be able to get a value from JavaScript and pass it to the bokeh server script and run a function with that new information that will manipulate the graph.

For example;

I have a series of buttons in JavaScript, when the button is pushed, I want to change the data from 'The number of Icecreams sold.' to 'the number of pizzas' by manipulating a variable.

I know that we can achieve this using bokeh's built-in buttons, but I'm really looking for a way for a way to achieve that from an 'on click' from the java side.

From my research, it seems there are plenty of ways to get python to do something to java, but not the other way around.

Is there any advice out there that might set me down the path?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own Javascript callbacks in the Python code. See the bokeh docs describing this [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html).

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to have java script outside of the python code affect the python code.

Comment: It is possible - just alter the `data` property of a column data source.